# Python, nltk is returning same list values to two different lists?

Tags: python

I wanted to segment a document in two lists, but this code is giving me same data in both the lists. I defined two separate dictionaries also which I am using here.

```
def feature_extractor(document):
support_features = []
attack_features = []
for sentence in document:
    if (word in sentence for word in supporting_ethos):
        support_features.append(sentence)
    if (word in sentence for word in attacking_ethos):
        attack_features.append(sentence)
return(attack_features , support_features)
```

Comment: You can put it all inside a list comprehension `[sentence for sentence in document if any(word in sentence for word in support_ethos )]`

Answer (score 2):

`(.. for .. in ...)` is [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).

```
>>> (x for x in [1,2])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002A1B828>
```

When it is used as predicate, it is always treated as truth.

```
>>> bool(_)
True
```

So both expressions `(word in sentence for word in supporting_ethos)` and `(word in sentence for word in attacking_ethos)` are evaluated as truth.

---

Do you mean to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with generator expression?

```
if any(word in sentence for word in supporting_ethos):
    ...
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it. and do you have any suggestions about where I could research more about coding for sentiment analysis

Comment: @user3753567, I don't know about the sentiment analysis.